# error: use of deleted function ‘Node::~Node()’

Tags: c++, unions

Here is an oversimplified version of my code

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <unordered_map>
    #include <iostream>




    struct ElementData
    {
        std::string tagName;
        std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> attributes;
    };

    enum NodeTypeEnum
    {
        None=-1,
        Text,
        Element
    };


    struct NodeType
    {
    private:

        union
        {
            std::string text;
            ElementData element;
        };
        
    public:
        NodeTypeEnum type;


    };



    struct Node
    {
        std::vector<Node> children;    
        NodeType type;


    };




    int main()
    {
        
        Node n;
        
    }
```

basically there is a node which has a type and a bunch of children.
the type is basically a tagged union, I make sure that if i am reading an element of the union it is the one I last wrote. This seems simple enough to me, so I am not sure why I  am getting the errors.

here are all the errors

```
Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cpp:55:10: error: use of deleted function ‘Node::Node()’
   55 |     Node n;
      |          ^
Main.cpp:41:8: note: ‘Node::Node()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   41 | struct Node
      |        ^~~~
Main.cpp:41:8: error: use of deleted function ‘NodeType::NodeType()’
Main.cpp:23:8: note: ‘NodeType::NodeType()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   23 | struct NodeType
      |        ^~~~~~~~
Main.cpp:29:21: error: union member ‘NodeType::<unnamed union>::text’ with non-trivial ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
   29 |         std::string text;
      |                     ^~~~
Main.cpp:30:21: error: union member ‘NodeType::<unnamed union>::element’ with non-trivial ‘ElementData::ElementData()’
   30 |         ElementData element;
      |                     ^~~~~~~
Main.cpp:41:8: error: use of deleted function ‘NodeType::~NodeType()’
   41 | struct Node
      |        ^~~~
Main.cpp:23:8: note: ‘NodeType::~NodeType()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   23 | struct NodeType
      |        ^~~~~~~~
Main.cpp:29:21: error: union member ‘NodeType::<unnamed union>::text’ with non-trivial ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::~basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
   29 |         std::string text;
      |                     ^~~~
Main.cpp:30:21: error: union member ‘NodeType::<unnamed union>::element’ with non-trivial ‘ElementData::~ElementData()’
   30 |         ElementData element;
      |                     ^~~~~~~
Main.cpp:55:10: error: use of deleted function ‘Node::~Node()’
   55 |     Node n;
      |          ^
Main.cpp:41:8: note: ‘Node::~Node()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   41 | struct Node
      |        ^~~~
Main.cpp:41:8: error: use of deleted function ‘NodeType::~NodeType()’
```

Why is ~NodeType() deleted? How can i fix this?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a union with a member that has a non-trivial destructor. So the union can't know how to destruct itself. That's why `NodeType::~NodeType` is deleted by default. That's what the message tells you.

You need to define the destructor yourself and properly call the destructor on the correct member.

Or, better yet, don't use unions at all. They are unsafe. Use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which is the standard library type for "tagged unions", or type-safe unions.

Comment: thanks, I just have two questions, 1, is there any performance cost if I use std::variant, 2, how would i go about calling the destructor on these objects;

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo It's not zero cost, but you need to look after the proper disposal of the `string`. Worth expanding on why you want a union of `string` and `ElementData`. There's probably an interesting story there, and this story will contain the details necessary to be able to tell you if there's a better path.

Comment: An aside: Start with `variant`. It's tried and trusted. If it turns out to be too slow, profiling will let you know.

Comment: sorry one last question, so in the destructor ~NodeType() do i just call the destructor of std::string if that is the active union member, and the destructor of ElementData if that is the active union member?

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo basically yes. And you need to do this also for copy/move constructors/assignments. Again, let me encourage you to not reinvent the wheel, especially since it's not a trivial task. Use `std::variant`.

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo hit: to use code blocks in comments use `  (grave accent)

Comment: @JadenAmatuzzo With a `union` on destruction and every time you change what the union represents, `string` to `ElementData` and vice-versa, the correct destructor must be called to clean up. You can't just swap back and forth willy-nilly. This means it needs to know if it's currently a `string` or an `ElementData` and always do the right thing. it's easy to screw up the book-keeping.